# fcm ionic custom sound

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using ionic with the ionic native plugin FCM. I have everything working, except I am unable to get my device to play a custom sound. Is this supposed to be the sound that plays when app is not in foreground (because no sound should play in foreground)? I have followed the instructions and placed "sound":alarm1" in both the notification, and/or data payload, and removed the notification payload all together. alarm1.mp3 is in the res/raw directory as well. I have used "sound":"alarm1" and "sound":"alarm1.mp3" in all of the cases also. What am I missing? I need to get the device to play 1 of 3 sounds on receipt of FCM.
I continue to get the default device notification sound is all cases.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Just found this https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-PushNotifications/m.FCM-GCM%20Payload It mentions that `Sounds on individual notifications were deprecated`. I tried changing the android target version to 25 and notification work fine so it seems like 26+ is the issue.

Comment: Where did you change the target version?